# Trying to get output where I get Date Time in Selected Frame with the PiName

Tags: c#, sqlite

So I made a function that return these things:

```
public ObservableCollection<Receipt> GetReceiptsWithInSelectedFrame(DateTime start, DateTime end)
{
  return GetReceitsByCommandString("select * from " + getTable() + 
         " where DateTime('" + start.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss") +
         "')" + " and DateTime( '" + start.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss") +
         "')");
```

but I get this error => logical error near "where": syntax error

Comment: Your sql statement is syntactically wrong, but you did not explain what conditions you want to apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DateTime` is not a recognised function in `SQL`. it is a `Type`. And you do not need it inside the query so just remove it.

So try this:

```
public ObservableCollection<Receipt> GetReceiptsWithInSelectedFrame(DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {
      return GetReceitsByCommandString("select * from " + getTable() + 
             " where ('" + start.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss") +
             "')" + " and ( '" + start.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss") +
             "')");
```